# Using AngularJS to post to server using $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, forms, angularjs

I'm sure this will be a duplicate of some other post, but I just can't find it?

I have just started looking at Angular and have written the following as per various sources online.

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-app="appAuthentication">

    <form name="authentication" method="post" data-ng-controller="AuthenticationController" data-ng-submit="doAuthentication(authentication)" novalidate>

        <fieldset>

            <label for="sign-in-email-address">Email address:</label>
            <input id="sign-in-email-address" name="sign-in-email-address" data-ng-model="authentication.emailAddress" type="text" required />

            <label for="sign-in-password">Password:</label>
            <input id="sign-in-password" name="sign-in-password" data-ng-model="authentication.password" type="password" required />

            <button type="submit">Go &#187;</button>

        </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>
```

And my Angular:

```
angular.module('appAuthentication', [])

    .controller('AuthenticationController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.authentication = {
            emailAddress: '',
            password: ''
        };

        $scope.doAuthentication = function(authentication) {

            // console.log('Hello ' + authentication.emailAddress);

            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/actions/authentication/sign-in.php',
                data : authentication.emailAddress
            })
            .success(function () {
                console.log('Success');
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log('Failure');
            });

        };

    }]);
```

In the console I am getting:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at k.$scope.doAuthentication (http://cms2.indypub.co.uk/static/scripts/core.js:16:4)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:176:88
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:193:165
    at k.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:111:373)
    at k.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:112:121)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:193:147)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:31:161
    at q (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:7:290)
    at HTMLFormElement.c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:31:143)
```

When I uncomment the first console.log in the JS the emailAddress is written out in the console.

Any pointers to where I am going wrong greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is in your controller dependencies, you have implicitly put `$http` in the function parameter but not in its array notation.

change:

```
controller('AuthenticationController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
  // your code
});
```

to

```
controller('AuthenticationController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 
  // your code
});
```

Furthermore, change your `name` value attributes in your `input` tags, make it so it conforms like a variable name - Since you'll be accessing these names when validating forms.

e.g. `<form name>.<input name>.$pristine` or `<form name>.<input name>.$error`

change:

```
    <label for="sign-in-email-address">Email address:</label>
    <input id="sign-in-email-address" name="sign-in-email-address" data-ng-model="authentication.emailAddress" type="text" required />

    <label for="sign-in-password">Password:</label>
    <input id="sign-in-password" name="sign-in-password" data-ng-model="authentication.password" type="password" required />
```

to:

```
    <label for="sign-in-email-address">Email address:</label>
    <input id="sign-in-email-address" name="sigInEmailAddress" data-ng-model="authentication.emailAddress" type="text" required />

    <label for="sign-in-password">Password:</label>
    <input id="sign-in-password" name="signInPassword" data-ng-model="authentication.password" type="password" required />
```

Comment: @ryeballar - spot on, worked immediately :) I suspect I have a long uphill journey ahead of me with Angular and the documentation seems to be quite difficult to follow, any good resources out there?

Comment: You can try codeschool(http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro) or https://egghead.io/

Comment: Note that in the egghead.io lessons list, you start at page 12 because thats where the very first uploads started